# How to share WebAssemly module between UI thread and service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker, webassembly, shared-worker

My web app is using a web assembly module for some non trivial operations. It has a service worker set up to handle push notifications. Both the main thread and the push notification handler need access to the web assembly module.

Is there a recommended approach to sharing the wasm module?

My first thought was to put it in the service worker and have the main thread call the worker, but then it might become idled and the worker would need to load and initialize the wasm module again which takes about 800ms.  I could also use a shared worker, but I don't believe the service worker can spawn a shared worker, so the solution wouldn't work if the main thread is closed.

Is there a canonical way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest adding information about the fact that the "in-memory object" you wish to share is a web assembly module to the title and the tags. Web Assembly changes the picture rather significantly, I would think.